# Pass argument with getx on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using getx to navigate between pages. I want to send my dummy string  to new page : This is my method :

```
   Future<dynamic> navigateWithTransition(Widget page,
      {dynamic arguments}) {
    return Get.to(() => page,
        arguments: arguments);
  }
```

Now I pass my argument to new page like this:

```
_navigatorService.navigateWithTransition(
  const PersonalInfoDegreePage(),
  arguments: "test",
);
```

But in PersonalInfoDegreePage page

```
class PersonalInfoDegreePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PersonalInfoDegreePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log.info(Get.arguments);
    return Scaffold(
```

I got  Get.arguments equal **null**. What is my wrong?

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. Not sure where the `.info` method comes from in your log, maybe it's an external package. But if you're just using the  `'dart:developer'` import and use `log(Get.arguments);` or regular `print`, both print out 'test'.

The only other thing I'll add is that you don't need to return a future in that function, it can be void.

```
  void navigateWithTransition(Widget page, {dynamic arguments}) {
    Get.to(() => page, arguments: arguments);
  }
```

Comment: log.info  is logger library. I don't think I got null has related to  `Future<dynamic>` . But instead of `.info` I used print `print(Get.arguments);`. I still got null @Loren.A

Comment: _navigatorService is injected by getIt and is lazySingleton. I wrote `navigateWithTransition` inside this class . I don't think again got null related to this part because  `navigateWithTransition` work and I can change page with that @Loren.A